# ffmpeg segments only the first part of my audio file

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I'm implementing a http live streaming server to send audio file to iOS devices.
No problem with Apple's tools, mediafilesegmenter, my files are valid and it works fine.

I'm trying now to segment the same file using ffmpeg. I've downloaded the last stable version which is the 0.10.2 for now.

Here is how I try to segment my mp3 file:

```
./ffmpeg -re -i input.mp3 -f segment -segment_time 10 -segment_list outputList.m3u8 -acodec libmp3lame -map 0 output%03d.mp3
```

It starts the mapping like expected but finish with only one .mp3 file.

Did I miss something in the process? 
Thanks in advance.

**edit**

Ok here is my latest command line:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k -map 0:0 -f segment -segment_time 10 -segment_list outputlist.m3u8 -segment_format mp3 'output%03d.mp3'
```

It still gives me only one file but the file is the hole song, not only one part.
Here is the output of ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg version 0.10.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers 
built on Apr 20 2012 07:08:29 with gcc 4.5.2   
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-libmp3lame   
    libavutil      51. 35.100 / 51. 35.100   
    libavcodec     53. 61.100 / 53. 61.100   
    libavformat    53. 32.100 /
        53. 32.100   
    libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100   
    libavfilter     2. 61.100 /  2. 61.100   
    libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100   
    libswresample   0.  6.100 /  0.  6.100   
    libpostproc    52.  0.100 /  52.  0.100 
    [mp3 @ 0x8e4f120] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5015510
Input #0, mp3, from 'BeachHouse-Myth.mp3':   
    Metadata:
            title           : Myth
            artist          : Beach House
            track           : /
            album           : Bloom
            disc            : /
            genre           : Alternative
            TSRC            : USSUB1296501   
    Duration: 00:04:18.69, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 320 kb/s
            Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 320 kb/s Output #0, segment, to 'stream%03d.mp3':   Metadata:
            title           : Myth
            artist          : Beach House
            track           : /
            album           : Bloom
            disc            : /
            genre           : Alternative
            TSRC            : USSUB1296501
            encoder         : Lavf53.32.100
            Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:   
    Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mp3 -> libmp3lame) 
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help 
    Truncating packet of size 1024 to 105ate=   0.0kbits/s    
    Truncating packet of size 1024 to 1 
    size=       0kB time=00:04:18.71 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s     video:0kB audio:4042kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead -100.000000%
```

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think the -segment_format switch might be needed.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I'll try once back at home tonight and keep you in touch.

Comment: @vipw unfortunately it didn't change anything. I've added the output of ffmpeg in my question.

Comment: Don't you want the output to be an m3u8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Audio only might be a bug. I contacted the FFMPEG player bug list, and a bug is filed: http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/ticket/1290