# Segmenting an audio stream or audio only file

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

There is need for an audio only link for HTTP-live streaming. I now use the segmenter in FFMPEG for the video, and that works great. However, when giving an audio-file the segmenter does not seem to work, just creates one segment.

The call to FFMPEG for the segmentation is:

> ffmpeg -i data/media/1/2/encoded.mp3 -y -c copy -flags global_header
>   -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 10 -segment_list data/media/1/2/fileList.txt -segment_format libmp3lame
>   data/media/1/2/segment_%05d.mp3

I did put as the -segment_format 'libmp3lame' in, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

The first step is the encoding, this is the bedbug output:

```
20:11:36,158 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG: ffmpeg version 0.10.2.git-d3d5e84 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
20:11:36,158 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:   built on May  2 2012 19:00:38 with clang 3.0 (tags/Apple/clang-211.10.1)
20:11:36,158 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:   configuration: --prefix=/opt/local --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-avfilter --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libdirac --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libmodplug --enable-libxvid --enable-libx264 --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --cc=/usr/bin/clang --arch=x86_64 --enable-yasm
20:11:36,158 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:   libavutil      51. 44.100 / 51. 44.100
20:11:36,158 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:   libavcodec     54. 12.100 / 54. 12.100
20:11:36,158 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:   libavformat    54.  3.100 / 54.  3.100
20:11:36,158 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:   libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100
20:11:36,158 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:   libavfilter     2. 66.101 /  2. 66.101
20:11:36,158 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:   libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
20:11:36,158 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:   libswresample   0. 10.100 /  0. 10.100
20:11:36,158 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:   libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
20:11:36,162 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG: Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'data/media/1/1/test.m4a':
20:11:36,162 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:   Metadata:
20:11:36,162 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:     major_brand     : mp42
20:11:36,162 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:     minor_version   : 1
20:11:36,163 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:     compatible_brands: mp42mp41
20:11:36,163 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:     creation_time   : 2011-12-07 18:53:04
20:11:36,163 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:   Duration: 00:00:24.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 40 kb/s
20:11:36,163 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:     Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 22050 Hz, stereo, s16, 39 kb/s
20:11:36,163 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:     Metadata:
20:11:36,163 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:       creation_time   : 2011-12-07 18:53:04
20:11:36,163 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:       handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
20:11:36,170 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG: [mpegts @ 0x7fe4c404d000] muxrate VBR, pcr every 4 pkts, sdt every 200, pat/pmt every 40 pkts
20:11:36,171 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG: Output #0, mpegts, to '/Users/Luuk/Documents/Java/idoms-server/data/media/1/2/encoded.mp3':
20:11:36,171 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:   Metadata:
20:11:36,171 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:     major_brand     : mp42
20:11:36,171 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:     minor_version   : 1
20:11:36,171 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:     compatible_brands: mp42mp41
20:11:36,171 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:     creation_time   : 2011-12-07 18:53:04
20:11:36,171 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:     encoder         : Lavf54.3.100
20:11:36,171 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:     Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 64 kb/s
20:11:36,171 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:     Metadata:
20:11:36,171 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:       creation_time   : 2011-12-07 18:53:04
20:11:36,171 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:       handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
20:11:36,171 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG: Stream mapping:
20:11:36,171 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (aac -> libmp3lame)
20:11:36,171 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG: Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
20:11:36,673 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG: size=     109kB time=00:00:12.79 bitrate=  69.5kbits/s    
20:11:37,156 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG: size=     209kB time=00:00:24.24 bitrate=  70.7kbits/s    
20:11:37,156 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG: video:0kB audio:190kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 10.301383%
```

Then the next is the segmentation (version 0.10.2 cannot do both at the same time yet):

```
20:11:37,211 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG: ffmpeg version 0.10.2.git-d3d5e84 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
    20:11:37,212 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:   built on May  2 2012 19:00:38 with clang 3.0 (tags/Apple/clang-211.10.1)
    20:11:37,212 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:   configuration: --prefix=/opt/local --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-avfilter --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libdirac --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libmodplug --enable-libxvid --enable-libx264 --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --cc=/usr/bin/clang --arch=x86_64 --enable-yasm
    20:11:37,212 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:   libavutil      51. 44.100 / 51. 44.100
    20:11:37,212 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:   libavcodec     54. 12.100 / 54. 12.100
    20:11:37,212 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:   libavformat    54.  3.100 / 54.  3.100
    20:11:37,212 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:   libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100
    20:11:37,212 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:   libavfilter     2. 66.101 /  2. 66.101
    20:11:37,212 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:   libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
    20:11:37,212 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:   libswresample   0. 10.100 /  0. 10.100
    20:11:37,212 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:   libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
    20:11:37,226 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG: [mpegts @ 0x7fccc2049800] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5016000
    20:11:37,226 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG: Input #0, mpegts, from '/Users/Luuk/Documents/Java/idoms-server/data/media/1/2/encoded.mp3':
    20:11:37,226 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:   Duration: 00:00:24.12, start: 1.376978, bitrate: 71 kb/s
    20:11:37,226 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:   Program 1 
    20:11:37,226 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:     Metadata:
    20:11:37,226 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:       service_name    : Service01
    20:11:37,226 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:       service_provider: FFmpeg
    20:11:37,226 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:     Stream #0:0[0x100](eng): Audio: mp3 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 64 kb/s
    20:11:37,226 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG: Output #0, segment, to '/Users/Luuk/Documents/Java/idoms-server/data/media/1/2/segment_%05d.mp3':
    20:11:37,226 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:   Metadata:
    20:11:37,226 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:     encoder         : Lavf54.3.100
    20:11:37,226 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:     Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: mp3 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, 64 kb/s
    20:11:37,226 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG: Stream mapping:
    20:11:37,226 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
    20:11:37,226 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG: Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    20:11:37,238 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG: size=       0kB time=00:00:24.28 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s    
    20:11:37,238 DEBUG ~ FFMPEG: video:0kB audio:190kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead -100.000000%
```

Comment: Is this a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241070/ffmpeg-segments-only-the-first-part-of-my-audio-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in FFMPEG. A bug has been filed: http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/ticket/1290